# Forgot my admin username and password in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I have forgotten my username and password of admin in MarkLogic 5. I tried to uninstall the software MarkLogic 5 and install that again. But every time it is asking for username and password when logging into the port 8001 after starting the server.

Can you please help me in getting that?

Answer (score 4):

Getting past the admin password is supposed to be hard (or impossible), of course. You mentioned uninstalling MarkLogic; if you aren't worried about preserving data, you can uninstall MarkLogic *and* remove the data directory (/var/opt/MarkLogic on Linux), then when you reinstall you'll be prompted to enter a new admin password.

---

edit: adding code from Jordan Stewart's comment to provide better formatting:

```
# stop Marklogic using a service 
sudo service MarkLogic stop 
# change directories to MarkLogic data dir 
cd var/opt/MarkLogic/ 
# remove everything including folder, this is dangerous 
sudo rm -rf * 
# start MarkLogic
sudo service MarkLogic start
```

Comment: You don't need uninstall actually. Just stop MarkLogic service, then flush the data directory, and start MarkLogic again. It will start with the initialization from an entirely clean slate.

Comment: On Linux to flush the data directory it this is generally:
`sudo service MarkLogic stop # stop Marklogic using a service
cd var/opt/MarkLogic/ # change directories to MarkLogic data dir
sudo rm -rf *   # remove everything including folder, this is dangerous
sudo service MarkLogic start # start MarkLogic `

Answer (score 1):

The default data directory is under C:\Program Files\MarkLogic. Remove c:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data directory and start ML, then run MarkLogic Admin url, which will open the url to http://127.0.0.1:8001/
It will ask initial setup. Type your new admin password there, then you will be cool bananas!