# How do I completely delete a MarkLogic database along with it's servers and forests?

Tags: database, gradle, admin, marklogic, marklogic-9

I have multiple databases in my local which I do not need. Can I run a curl script or a REST API command where I can delete the database, it's servers and all of the forests so that I can use gradle to just deploy them again?

I have tried to manually delete the server first, then the database and then the forests. This is a lengthy process.

I want a single command to do the whole job for me instead of manually having to delete the components one by one which is possible through the admin interface.

Comment: If you are already using gradle to deploy your application why don't use gradle tasks to undeploy it?

Answer (score 1):

Wagner Michael has a fair point in his comment. If you already used (ml-)Gradle to create servers and databases, why not use its `mlUndeploy -Pconfirm=true` task to get rid of them? You could potentially even use a fake project, with stub configs to get rid of a fairly random set of databases and servers, though that still takes some manual work.

By far the quickest way to reset your entire MarkLogic, is to stop it, and wipe its data directory. This SO question gives instructions on how to do it, as part of a solution to recover when you lost your admin password:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27803923/918496

HTH!